# Radio Button Selection for Multifield

Tags: aem

I need an identifier in tabs such that author can specify which tab will open at page load Below is my dialog.xml.

```
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <typeconfigs
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            fieldLabel="Accordion"
                            name="./options"
                            xtype="customconfigmultifield">
                        <fieldConfigs jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <option
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    hidden="{Boolean}true"
                                    name="option_name"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                            <optionval
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                                    fieldLabel="Title"
                                    maxLength="{Long}60"
                                    name="optionval"
                                    xtype="textfield"/>
                            <openaccordion
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    name="selectaccordion"
                                    type="radio"
                                    xtype="selection">
                                <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                    <one
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            text="Open at Page Load"
                                            value="in"/>
                                </options>
                            </openaccordion>
                        </fieldConfigs>
                        <limit
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                maxVal="{Long}15"/>
                    </typeconfigs>
                </items>
```

But now i am not getting the behavior of radio button, means i can tick all radio buttons inside each tab that i add via dialog. Any idea how can i make that switch possible. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but an idea for the decomposition: Keep multifield to store titles only and create a separated widget, radio or even selection (better UX probably) that will list all the titles. You would need to write a custom `optionsProvider` but that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The radio button, as defined in your current structure needs two options, and the value of the field will toggle between the two options.In case you just want to show one option, I'd recommend using a `checkbox`.

I've tried to answer your question by assuming you decide to go ahead with a checkbox (which has two states, `true` and `false`). In case you decide to add a second radio button, you can change the values of true and false to the values that you have defined; (one of which is `in`)

What you are looking for is a set of custom listeners that

i) iterate through each multifield item, checking the value of `<openAccordion>` of the currently clicked multifield item.

ii) Set it to `true` for the current multifield item

iii) Set the value of `<openAccordion>` to `false` for all other multifield items.

The event that you'd require is `selectionchanged`.

Once you verify that the properties are getting set correctly, all you need is another listener that triggers on the `loadcontent` event, that looks for the multifield item with the value of `<openAccordion>` as `true` and displays that tab, hiding the rest.

As an aside, in my opinion, you might want to restructure your dialog, something similiar to what @Mathew posted in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <tabs
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/multifield"
                                        composite="{Boolean}true">
                                        <field
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/container"
                                            name="./options">
                                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                <wrapper
                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                    jcr:title="eon-feh-service-po.components.siteadmin.question.v1.dialog.tab.general.answeroptions.multifieldexpand"
                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                                                    <layout
                                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/collapsible"/>
                                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
<isDropoutOpt
                                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/radiogroup"
                                                            name="./isDropoutOpt"
                                                            renderReadOnly="{Boolean}true"
                                                            text="Option selection leads to dropdown?">
                                                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                                                <radioYes
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/radio"
                                                                    text="YES"
                                                                    value="yes"/>
                                                                <radioNo
                                                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/radio"
                                                                    text="NO"
                                                                   value="no"/>
                                                            </items>
                                                        </isDropoutOpt>
```

Comment: The above code works for me. Use granite instead of coral:
coral - granite/ui/components/foundation/form/radio

granite - granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/radiogroup